# Problem with Login Screen and Sudo Comand

Tags: 12.04, login, sudo

I'm new to Linux world, infact I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 yesterday on my computer. I have Dual-COre processor, 2GB RAM, 500GB HardDisk, No graphics card and XP in parallel.
I'm facing So many problems in Ubuntu:

1) Login Screen is on left side and only half of it is visible.

2) I logged in with password which I had Set while installing Ubuntu but still it is showing me Guest-Hbicaz@ somthing

3) Sudo command is not working. When i tried to install gedit using this command `"sudo apt-get install gedit"`. It is giving me these errors

```
sudo: unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted
sudo: setresuid() [0, 0, 0] -> [118, -1, -1]: Operation not permitted
```

I'm new to Ubuntu.

I have searched to solve the Login screen problem but I cant solve because sudo command is not working

Comment: Seems you are loged in as guest. On the login screen (maby you don't see it because the screen issue) there is normaly an option for logging in with your username.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But i can see the user name on the login screen. One is guest and second is my username which I set while installing. I always login with my username not as guest :/

Comment: I just logged in as guest on my desktop. And your problems with the terminal are identical what i have expired on my guest account. I guess you use wubi?